# How to best prevent adding content to a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary object with three key/value pairs.  I want the values to be able to be modified, but i want to prevent being able to add more.  Is there a best approach to prevent adding new key/value pairs?  I was thinking of just hiding the Add method.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be a Dictionary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just encapsulate the dictionary within a custom class, and don't provide a way to add.

That being said, if there are always only three values, I would consider just using a class with three properties instead of a dictionary.  There is no point in making a dictionary if the keys are fixed and known in advance - three properties will have a simpler, less error prone API and be more efficient.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to not use a dictionary if there are only 3 values.

Comment: In this case there are three, but in other cases there may be four, five, or just two.  i.e. for a report generating tool, each report section has a fixed number of subsections.  So I was thinking of an interface, IReportSection, and each class that extends it would use the dictionary, but would have different entries.

Comment: @pendraggon87 You can always just make the interface or class provide an indexer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) instead of actually using a Dictionary.  Since each class has a fixed # (however many it is) for that class, a dictionary isn't really necessary...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks for the idea - makes life easier :)

Answer (score 4):

Create a wrapper class that prohibits those operations, then wrap your dictionary in an instance once you want to make the key set read-only.  (For example, explicitly implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add()` and have it throw `NotSupportedException`.)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding is almost never the correct thing to do (I assume that by "hiding" you mean subclassing and using `new` to hide the base class' method). If you hide the `Add` method and a consumer casts your object back to the base class, they will be able to access the hidden method and add items to it.

As others have suggested, the best approach here is to probably create a wrapper which encapsulates an `IDictionary` and does not provide a way to add.